# Order by value Inside IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have 3 tables in my database.

**Region** (has a List Of) **Country** (has a List Of) **City**

All of the tables have their own Id, the parentId and a Name. For Example:

```
public class Country 
{
   public int CountryId {get;set;}
   public int RegionId {get;set;} //FK to Region
   public string CountryName {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<City> Cities {get;set;}
}
```

In SQL I can make a query like that.

```
SELECT top 5 r.* 
FROM Region r
JOIN Country c on r.RegionId=c.RegionId
JOIN City ct on ct.CountryId=c.CountryId
ORDER By ct.CityName
```

I get the regions ordered by CityName. Is there any way I can do the same on linq?

I'm trying something like:

```
var regionOrdered = context.Regions
        .OrderBy(x=>x.Countries
                     .SelectMany(y=>y.Cities
                                   .Select(u=>u.CityName)))
        .Take(5).ToList();
```

But this doesn't works... Any ideas?

-----UPDATE----

Thank you for your answers, but I need to do with and OrderBy.

My problem is that I need to use a ExtensionMethod that is in my project:

```
static IQueryable<T> ApplySeveralOrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryableBase, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderProp) where T : class
```

Inside the method, I have an line like that:

```
queryableBase = queryableBase.OrderBy(orderProp);
```

I only want to know if its possible to do that order with an Expression so I can use the extension or if it's impossible.

Comment: This LINQ query has nothing to do with the SQL query. Its like writing `ORDER BY (SELECT .......)`. Use `Select` first to get the fields you want, including `CityName` and then use `.OrderBy(x=>x.CityName)`. If you want all cities, use `Cities` as the root, not `Regions`. Does `City` have a `Region` property?

Comment: What doesn't work ? Is context.Region an IEnumerable in your c# code ? You bothered to write plural names for collections (Countries, Cities) (which is good !) but not for Region so I would assume you're trying to call a sort method on an object that isn't enumerable.

Comment: In your SQL you also get duplicated regions. So what you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: If you want all cities by name you can use `context.Cities.OrderBy(c=>c.CityName)`. If `City` has a `Country` property, and `Country` a `Region`, they'll be loaded when you try to access them. To load them all at ones, `context.Cities.Include(=>c.Country).ThenInclude(c=>c.Region).OrderBy(c=>c.CityName);`. If you want to flatten all in a single row - what properties do you want to load?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv

 I doesn't have duplicates in my SQL because I only have r.* in the select, it works like i want.

Comment: @Calimero
Yes, context.Regions is also an enumerable, I deteled the 's' writing the question, sorry :)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos

I can't do that, i need the query to start from the regions Enumerable, and the result should be the top 5 ordered regions by cities name

Comment: That's not what your SQL query does. Assuming Cities is the most granular, it returns the region rows for the first 5 cities by name. You can use query form instead of fluent form in LINQ to easily do the same `(from r in ctx.Regions from cnt in r.Countries from c in cnt.Cities order by c.CityName select r).Take(5)`

Comment: @DaniHernandez Can you tell us more about what exactly doesnt work ? Do you have an error ? An unexpected result ? Which exactly ? Etc...

Comment: I don't get the point of your original sql. If you have records: `Cancun<Mexico<NorthAmerica,` `Ottawa<Canada<NorthAmerica`; your result will be: `NorthAmerica`, `NothAmerica`

Comment: What are you doing in ApplySeveralOrderBy() ?

Answer (score 0):

pretty much the same way you do it in SQL.

```
var regionOrdered =
      (from r in context.Regions
      join c in context.Countries on r.CountryId equals c.CountryId
      join ct in context.Cites on c.CityId equals ct.CityId
      orderby ct.CityName
      select r)
       .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to do with and OrderBy, i need to use a ExtensionMethod that is in my project:  
static IQueryable<T> ApplySeveralOrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryableBase, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderProp) where T : class

Inside the method, I have an queryableBase = queryableBase.OrderBy(orderProp);

I only want to know if its possible to do that order with an Expression so i can use the extension or if it's impossible

Comment: @DaniHernandez please [edit] your question.